# using REGEX to 2 combination of letter in a list of strings python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the string that contain 2 set of 3 characters such has:

```
x = ['USDGBP.q', 'CADUSD.q', 'GBPCAD.q']
```

I am trying to extract the string that contains USD & GBP. but the USD and GBP coud be GBPUSD or USDGBP

so in the example, it would return

```
'USDGBP.q'
```

any way to achieve this through regex?

Comment: See http://ideone.com/Cm3Wzm

Comment: Why are you striclly looking at a regex solution?

Comment: thank you, would accept as answer if you want to post below

Comment: I though regex was the only way :)

Comment: `re.search(r'(USDGBP|GBPUSD) (CADUSD|USDCAD) (GBPCAD|CADGBP)', stringtomatch)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
x = ['USDGBP.q', 'CADUSD.q', 'GBPCAD.q']
print([s for s in x if 'USD' in s and 'GBP' in s])
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/Cm3Wzm).

It will return the items from `x` that contain both `USD` and `GBP`.

Answer (score 1):

You can [*emulate*](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/and-in-regex/) **Logical AND** with regex using positive look-aheads. This strictly matches `GBPUSD` or `USDGBP`.

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?=.*USD)(?=.*GBP)')
>>> x = ['USDGBP.q', 'CADUSD.q', 'GBPCAD.q', 'GBPUSD.q']
>>> print filter(lambda item: re.findall(pattern, item), x)
['USDGBP.q', 'GBPUSD.q']
```

But if you needed a more lenient regex to match any string containing both tokens:

`r'.*(?=.*USD).*(?=.*GBP).*')`